# Node.js scope error

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm getting the following error :

```
/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/apps/authentication/routes.coffee:6
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  ^
ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/apps/authentication/routes.coffee:6:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/apps/authentication/routes.coffee:15:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.require.extensions..coffee (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:22:21)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/app.js:31:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

While trying to pass the (app) variable to the following require :

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

require('coffee-script');

var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes
**require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);**

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Using the app variable in the following file :

```
routes = (app) -> 
app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
    res.render 'views/login',
        title: 'Login'
        stylesheet: 'login'
module.exports = routes
```

I know that the variable scope is different from one JS file to another. But why does the following line :

```
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);
```

Doesn't pass the app variable?

Comment: We're probably going to need to see `(some other code here)`

Comment: I updated the code and the stack error.

Comment: I found a possible solution. By removing the var infront of the app variable, I'm not getting the error anymore. Is it because I'm changing the variable scope?

     app = express();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript is very sensitive to indentation. This code should work:

```
routes = (app) -> 
    app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
        res.render 'views/login',
            title: 'Login'
            stylesheet: 'login'
module.exports = routes
```

Comment: This isn't actually correct. The `module.export...` line is indented, meaning that it'll be compiled _within_ the `routes` function. That means that the exports line won't actually get run. It needs to be unindented.

Answer (score 3):

Right here:

```
ReferenceError: app is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nblavoie/Desktop/HotPie/HotPie/apps/authentication/routes.coffee:6:3)
```

The error isn't in `app.js`, it's in your CoffeeScript file. Check out [what it's compiling to](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aroutes%20=%20%28app%29%20-%3E%0Aapp.get%20%27/login%27,%20%28req,%20res%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20res.render%20%27views/login%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%3a%20%27Login%27,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stylesheet%3a%20%27login%27%0A%0Amodule.exports%20=%20routes):

```
var routes;

routes = function(app) {};

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  return res.render('views/login', {
    title: 'Login',
    stylesheet: 'login'
  });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

Notice that `routes` is an empty function? Yep, you missed an indent. Changing your CoffeeScript to the following should fix it (notice the indentation of `app.get` and everything after it):

```
routes = (app) ->
    app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
        res.render 'views/login',
            title: 'Login',
            stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```